# VB.Net Array with string as key

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, visual-studio

hope someone can help me with this:

Is something like this possible in VB.net:

```
Dim XYZ() as String
xyz("FRIST_ENTRY") = "MESSAGE"
```

And use this later like:

```
Button.Text = xyz("FIRST_ENTRY")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are no associative arrays in Vb.Net. I think you should use a Dictionary with a string as Key.

The initialization should be like:

```
Dim myNewDictionary As new Dictionary(Of string, string)
```

Then you can just add items to it using .add():

```
myNewDictionary.Add("someStringAsKey", "someStringAsValue")
```

Microsoft docs entry about the Dictionary:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2

PS. Sorry about any misspellings or typos, English is not my main language.